# Retrieve Properties of HashSet passed as Object

Tags: c#, hashset

I'm maintaining part of an application which takes an entity framework entity as an object and returns a list of all its properties and corresponding values.

The method looks something like this:

```
public static List<string> ExtractAttributes(object data)
{
    List<string> attributes = new List<string>();

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(data))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}  Value: {1}  Type: {2}", property.Name, property.GetValue(data), data.GetType());

        attributes.Add(property.Name);
    }
    return attributes;
}
```

On calling this method with the following object:

```
ExtractAttributes(HashSet<Dog> dogs);
```

The method returns Count and Comparer (properties of HashSet) rather than properties of Dog. Therefore it is necessary to convert the `data` object to the first object of the hashset collection (it only needs to be the first object in the set for reasons too long to explain in detail).

The code I've written to do this is as follows:

```
public static List<String> ExtractAttributes(object data)
{
...
if (data.GetType().IsGenericType &&
    data.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(HashSet<>))
{
    List<object> hashSetAsList = new List<object>((IEnumerable<object>)data);
    if (hashSetAsList.Count > 0)
    {
        data = hashSetAsList[0];
    }
}
...
}
```

Is there any way to improve this ugly-looking code given the constraint of being unable to alter anything else in the method/return type?

**Edit**
The ExtractAttributes method is recursive (in a way which depends on the logic of some external XML) but can be represented as:

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(data))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}  Value: {1}  Type: {2}", property.Name, property.GetValue(data), data.GetType());

    if (property.GetValue(data).GetType().IsGenericType)
    {
        attributes.AddRange(ExtractAttributes(property.GetValue(data)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you *only* want to use this special case for hashsets, not lists or arrays or...

Comment: It's not ugly. Needs a little formatting, no need to check `.Count`.

Comment: @Rawling it's a special case for HashSets because of how EF returns the entity.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata surely without the count I run the risk of a Null Reference Exception if the object is an empty HashSet?

Comment: OK. If you don't mind it applying to other collection types too then the code becomes nicer (see Maarten) but otherwise you don't have a choice but to check it is a `HashSet<something>` and as you've seen that's not very easy.

Comment: Maybe you should provide full code, if you're testing for null it should be at the top.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata If the hash-set doesn't contain any items, and you omit the `.Count > 0` check, then retrieving the first item by index 0 `[0]` will result in an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it more generally trying to cast the object as a simple non-generic `IEnumerable`.

```
public static List<String> ExtractAttributes(object data) {
    ...
    if (data is IEnumerable) {
        var enumerator = ((IEnumerable)data).GetEnumerator();
        if (enumerator.MoveNext() && enumerator.Current != null) {
            data = enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And if you really only want this to be done for hash-set's, I guess you can add your criteria to check to hash-set's:

```
if (data is IEnumerable &&
    data.GetType().IsGenericType &&
    data.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(HashSet<>)) {
```

Comment: I think this solves the problem most elegantly (and I wasn't clear about the HashSet only restriction) so I will accept it. 

Does it offer performance benefits over my cast to List (it's not an issue here since the object is tiny and the HashSet has 1 object) for larger lists?

Comment: I'm not sure about measurable performance gains, I doubt it if the hash-set contains small amounts of objects. The difference between your solution and my solution is that in your solution you are iterating through the hash-set, and creating a new list out of it, and then taking the first item, where in my solution I start iterating the hash-set but stop after the first item. So yes the "amount of work to be done" is much less. Still, I doubt you would notice.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating an overload of `ExtractAttributes` method that accepts, say, `IEnumerable<object>`. This way, a more specific overload will be chosen when you pass HashSet.

Comment: `given the constraint of being unable to alter anything else in the method/return type`

Comment: Well, the method and return type actually stays as is, you just need to define another one

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately there is the issue of the method being called recursively, so the first object that is passed in is `Owner` which has an `ICollection<Dog>` which is implemented as `HashSet<Dog>`. The method is then called again recursively on the `HashSet` object but it's not possible to change the arguments in this case (I'll add an edit to explain in more detail).

Comment: The other issue is that overload resolution takes place at compile time, not at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could just cast the HashSet and take the first Element

```
HashSet<object> castedObject = Object as HashSet<object>;

object first = castedObject != null ? castedObject.First() : "";
```

Comment: A `HashSet<Dog>` is not a `HashSet<object>`.